# What happens to the black stone in Whisperer in the Darkness?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, mi-go, cthulhu-mythos

In the HPL story *Whisperer in the Darkness* a black stone (presumably a Tablet of some sort) is sought after by the Mi-Go. As one of my favourite stories, I was wondering, did anything happen after the events of the story? *Does the Tablet resurface?*

I'm asking primarily so I can run a roleplaying game of Call of Cthulhu for some friends of mine, and I'm wishing to extend the story of the tablet, but I don't want to step on the toes of continuity, if at all possible.

I found mention of *G'harne Fragments* from a book by *Brian Lumley* but I can't find a reference to which story, or whether the two black stones are one and the same.

Does this give any clues, that might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Medusa's Coil there's a reference to "de black stone outen Big Zimbabwe" but as far as I can tell from a quick skim through the story this is unrelated to the black stone in The Whisperer in Darkness. I don't know of any other references to the stone. In fact I think the Mi-Go only appear in one other story, The Mountain of Madness.

I wonder if Lovecraft was thinking of the Rosetta stone, which is black(ish) and covered in hieroglyphics.

Comment: I've given you the bounty as you give about as much detail as seems possible for the stone, give the lack of mi-go stories.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful. I think the information just isn't there. However it did give me an excuse to reopen my Lovecraft Collected Stories and while away some happy hours!

Comment: You shouldn't need an excuse for that!